# :: operator necessary to use with tolower()?

Tags: c++, operators

```
transform(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), mystr.begin(), tolower);
```

I am using the transform function to make a string all lowercase letters, but even after  writing "using namespace std;" at the top of my program I get a whole bunch of errors(when writen like above). When I include the :: operator before the tolower parameter (such as below) I don't. Why is this? I thought the tolower function was in the std namespace and It would work like I have above.

```
transform(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), mystr.begin(), ::tolower);
```

I have the following includes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
```

In the error message I see:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'transform(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, ...
```

then it the place where 'tolower' is in the parameter list

```
, <unresolved overloaded function type>);'
```

Comment: When you have "a whole bunch of errors" it's useful to say exactly what they are.

Answer (score 5):

Well , this is a bit complicated. Adding `#include <cctype>` would probably appear to fix your problem. However there is a bit more going on.

There are these two versions of `tolower`:

```
int std::tolower(int ch);                           // #include <cctype>

template<typename charT>
charT std::tolower(charT ch, const std::locale& loc);    // #include <locale>
```

but there also may be this version:

```
int ::tolower(int ch);    // #include <cctype> or #include <ctype.h>
```

because implementations are allowed to inject names from `std` into the global namespace. Also, you can't count on `cctype` or `locale` being included or not, because any standard include may also include any other standard include.

---

It looks like you are intending to use the version from `<cctype>`.  However, that would be a bug . If you check the documentation for that version of `tolower` you will see that the argument should be *converted to `unsigned char`* before being passed to the function.

IOW, passing a `char` with negative value to the cctype version of `tolower` causes undefined behaviour. (Although common implementations support it because it's such a common mistake).

To correct your code and still use the cctype version, you could write:

```
#include <cctype>

// ...

transform(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), mystr.begin(), 
    [](char ch) { return std::tolower( (unsigned char)ch ); } );
```

although it seems a bit simpler to use:

```
for (char &ch : mystr)
    ch = std::tolower( (unsigned char)ch );
```

The `<locale>` version would look like (remembering that it is a function template):

```
#include <locale>
#include <functional>

// ...

transform(mystr.begin(), mystr.end(), mystr.begin(), 
    std::bind( std::tolower<char>, std::placeholders::_1, std::locale() ) );
```

or

```
std::locale loc;

for ( char &ch : mystr )
    ch = std::tolower(ch, loc);
```

Answer (score 4):

It's to resolve the conflict between the overloads of `tolower` between
`<cctype>`'s `int tolower(int c)` and  `<locale>`'s template `<typename charT> charT tolower(charT c, locale const& loc)`

`::tolower` use that of global scope

Comment: ... and the solution is to cast `tolower` to the appropriate type, which will force resolution: `static_cast<int (*)(int)>(tolower)`

Comment: (though as Matt McNabb points out, that's not quite correct).

Answer (score 3):

What is the header file that you have included? Make sure, you include `<cctype>` and not `<ctype.h>` .. In the `<cctype>` all functions have been defined in namespace std.

Answer (score 2):

The `::` is to say it is in the global namespace. It just makes it clear